# Multiple setValue on multicheckbox

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm currently working on a Zend 2 project and I have some problems for **setValue** on multicheckbox with variable.

So, I have an array with all my values to pass in setValue (the values are correct for example I have : `1|6|7` ). Now I want to use the function setValue for checked box :

```
$form->get('checklist_days')->setValue(array($arrayDays));
```

But with this, It's checked only the last box (7 in the example above) in the array and not all the boxs in the array...
How to deal with that ?

Thanks per advance!

PokeRwOw

Answer (score -1):

Change `$form->get('checklist_days')->setValue(array($arrayDays));`

to this `$form->get('checklist_days')->setValueOptions(array($arrayDays));`

`setValue()` is used to populate a single element, while `setValueOptions()` is used to populate multiple elements.